# set width of column in percentage in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how to set width of column in percentage in highcharts

```
options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        xAxis: {
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.y +' '+ this.x.toLowerCase()+''+this.percentage;
            }
        },
         plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointWidth: 50
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This is not a PHP question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, percent point width is not supported.

Comment: my question is....why is it not supported?

Comment: You can post your suggestion in our uservoice here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com